# Pipe ex command into vim register?

Tags: vim

I would like to do get the output of an ex command placed in a register. I know there is the :redir command, but that requires three commands to accomplish the task. Is there a native way to do it in one command?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you'll get much shorter than...

```
:redir @a | echo "This will end up in register a." | redir END
```

...without writing a function.